# Sort JSON objects

Tags: objective-c, json, ios5, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have 3 `MutableArray`'s, but only want to use one of them, to sort all of them in the tableView.

```
jsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //NAME
jsonStations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //URL
jsonSubtitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //TABLEVIEW CELL SUBTITLE
```

I want to use the `jsonArray` to sort all the json data in my tableView.

Heres how i get the json data:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxxxx.com/xxx.json"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(connection)
    {
        jsonData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }

...

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSArray *arrayOfItems = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"items"];

    for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfItems) {
        NSString *titles = [diction objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *subtitles = [diction objectForKey:@"subtitle"];
        NSString *station = [diction objectForKey:@"url"];

        [jsonArray addObject:titles];
        [jsonSubtitle addObject:subtitles];
        [jsonStations addObject:station];

        [self.tableview reloadData];

    }    
}
```

Sooo how do i sort my jsonArray by the `titles` and show then sorted in the tableView ?

Comment: XCode is the development environment. It's your editor, and it compiles and links your app. It does not do anything with your JSON. For that, you use Objective-C and the iOS library. I've changed the title and the tags accordingly.

Comment: `[self.tableview reloadData];`  is this works properly ? if so all you need to do is sort jsonArray before calling `[self.tableview reloadData];`

Comment: As far as i can see.. yes.. but i haven't debug'ed it tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can sort it:

```
 NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [jsonArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *title1, NSString *title2)
             {
                 if ([title1 compare:title2] > 0)
                     return NSOrderedAscending;
                 else
                     return NSOrderedDescending;
             }]; 
[jsonArray setArray:sortedArray];
```

Comment: Where shall i insert that ?

Comment: but don't just INSERT this piece of code. that's just an example of how to sort

Comment: Ah okay.. is it possible you could make the sort function to fit my code ? in new to json, and not quite into Obj-c

Comment: i've added a line. if your TableView takes data from jsonArray that should be enough